# Can't uninstall an application. Are there any alternatives?

Tags: windows-7, installer

I'm trying to uninstall an application from my Windows 7 machine, but the uninstall fails with the following error:

> There is a problem with this Windows
>   Installer package. A program required
>   for this install to complete could not
>   be run. Contact your support personnel
>   or package vendor

Is there a safe alternative way to remove this application. Maybe manually or something. I know I can delete the application files, but can I somehow get rid of the entry in the "Add/Remove Programs" dialog too?

Thanks.

Comment: "Can't uninstall"... But can't uninstall WHAT? Plese, try to improve your question title. Maybe something along the lines "Can't uninstall an application because Windows Installer failure." (even though it's not a question)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try reinstalling the application complete, and then uninstalling.  This works for a lot of annoying pieces of software that will not go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) - available on [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) for quick installation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open the "Add/Remove Programs" dialog.
2. Right click on the offending application and click "Repair" in the context menu.
3. When the repair is done, uninstall the application as usual.